# Partial derivative of matrix dot vector wrt the vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, partial-derivative

Let:

- $m$ ("**m**ultiplier") denote a $K \times N$ matrix
- $w$ ("**w**eight") denote a $N \times 1$ vector
- $c$ ("**c**onstraints") denote a $K \times 1$ vector

Define a "distance" function as:

$$
f(w,m)=c- |m \cdot w|,
$$

where "|" is the absolute value operator.

What's the partial derivative of $f$ w.r.t. $w$? The answer has to be a $K \times N$ matrix.

---

**My attempt**:

$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w} = - m \odot s,
$$

where $\odot$ is the element-wise product operator, and $s=(s_1, s_2, ..., s_N)$ is of the same shape of $m$ with repeated columns $s_1=s_2=...=s_N$:

$$
s_j = \text{sign}(m \cdot w).
$$

I'm sure there is a better way of writing this out without using $\odot$?

---

**Background**:

I'm trying to write out the `fprime_ieqcons` in [`scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin_slsqp.html).

The `f(w,m)` above correponds to `f_ieqcons` in `fmin_slsqp`.

Comment: You can get rid of the elementwise product by creating a diagonal matrix from the sign vector, i.e.
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}
  = -{\sf Diag}\Big({\sf sign}(Mw)\Big)\cdot M
$$